# Is it ok to say "Don't visit the internet"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I read the following recommendation of our IT department:

> Don't **visit** the Internet with Windows XP machines

We're a German company. Is this sentence ok?

I would have expected

> Don't browse the Internet with Windows XP machines.

or

> Don't use the Internet with Windows XP machines.

Comment: Yes, one "uses" or "accesses" the Internet... "visit" suits a page/site/url better.

Comment: @Thomas W - Access is prior to browsing or using (or even visiting, which implies personal presence entering a space, historically for charitable or humanitarian purposes), so I'd suggest avoiding 'visit' and using 'access'. I'd also suggest 'on' rather than 'with'.

Comment: @LeonConrad: thanks for pointing out the `on` thing. Otherwise it could be interpreted as: *Don't use the Internet on Windows 7 machines, because the Internet has dangerous Windows XP machines, which could be harmful.* Right?

Comment: @ThomasW. It took me a while to get what you meant, but yes. It's not the most obvious reading, though. Think of writing 'with' a pen 'on ' paper. The computer is like the paper. The software is like the pen. It's not a perfect analogy, but it's the reading I'd go to first before thinking of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - both of your alternates are better. You can *visit* a website, but not the Internet as a whole. It definitely doesn't work if you're also trying to tell people not to use *any* internet functions, such as email, messaging services, Skype, etc.

The sentence 'browse the internet' would probably be taken as specific to the web - and not relate to email and other services either. So, if you want to stop people using the internet at all on XP machines, I'd use:

> Don't **use the internet** on Windows XP machines.

If it's just the web you're talking about, try:

> Don't **browse the web** on Windows XP machines.

Comment: I like this answer most, because it makes clear that our IT department should really be more specific as the current sentence leaves room for interpretation. I'm glad I asked this question here :-)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with visit, *per se*. It's just not convention.

Answer (score 1):

Just like d'alar'cop says: I´d say "Don't access the internet...". One visits a page, but you access the internet. When I visit the internet, it sounds more like ring the door bell, enter the building and drink a cup of tea with internet.